# Galois group of tamely ramified extension

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $p$ be a prime and let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Suppose $L/K$ is a tamely ramified Galois extension. I want to show that if $\sigma$ is a lift of the Frobenius element of the Galois group of the residue field extension and $\tau$ is a generator of $\textrm{Gal}(L/E)$ where $E$ is the maximal unramified subextension of $L$, then $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1} = \tau^q$ where $q$ is the order of the residue field of $K$.

I know that $L = E(\lambda^{1/e}$) where $\lambda$ is some uniformizer for $E$ and $e$ is the ramification index of $L/K$. If $\sigma(\lambda^{1/e})$ is another $e$-th root of $\lambda$, then I can show the desired relation holds. However, it seems to me that we can't be sure this is the case, because $\lambda$ may not be in $K$.

Comment: The title doesn't correspond to the question.  (To answer the implied question in the title, the Galois group is *not* always a semidirect product of the inertia group with a lift of Frobenius.)

Comment: @user760870  I think it is a semidirect product provided it's a tamely ramified extension a $p$-adic field? Using OP's notation, Galois group is generated by $\sigma, \tau$, subjected to $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1} = \tau^q$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pisco Yes you are missing something. I suggest thinking about Galois extensions $K/\mathbf{Q}_p$ of degree $4$ (when $p$ is odd) .

Comment: @user760870 Yes, you're right. I had the wrong impression that $\tau$ and $\sigma$ generates disjoint subgroups, which is not always the case. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: @user760870 So are you saying this relation may not always hold, or just that it may not be enough to determine the Galois group?

Comment: The relation holds, and @pisco's argument is correct. The point is that the extension need not be split (which only comes up in the title not the question); you could have $G = \mathbf{Z}/4 \mathbf{Z}$ and $\tau$ of order $2$ and $\sigma$ of order $4$ (so $\sigma^2 = \tau$), or $G = (\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})^2$ with $\tau$ of order $2$ and $\sigma$ of order $2$. Both arise as Galois groups of tamely ramified degree $4$ extensions with ramification degree $2$. Both will have $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1} = \tau = \tau^q$ for $q$ odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer of the totally ramified extension $L/E$. We have a map:
$$\theta: \text{Gal}(L/E) \to U_L/U^{(1)}_L\qquad \tau_0\mapsto \tau_0(\pi)/\pi$$
where $U_L$ is the unit group of $\mathcal{O}_L$, and $U^{(1)}_L = 1+\mathfrak{p}_L$. This map is independent of the unifromizer $\pi$ chosen. Its kernel is the wild ramification group, which is trivial since $L/K$ is assumed to be tamely ramified. Hence $\theta$ is injective.

Denote $\tau(\pi)\equiv a\pi \pmod{\mathfrak{p}_L^2}$. Then
$$\tag{1}\sigma\tau(\pi) \equiv \sigma(a)\sigma(\pi) \equiv a^q\sigma(\pi) \pmod{\mathfrak{p}_L^2}$$
because $\sigma$ acts like Frobenius. Moreover, since $\theta$ is independent of unifromizer, we have $\tau(\sigma(\pi))\equiv a\sigma(\pi) \pmod{\mathfrak{p}_L^2}$, so
$$\tau^2(\sigma(\pi))\equiv \tau(a)\tau(\sigma(\pi))\equiv \tau(a)a\sigma(\pi) \equiv a^2\sigma(\pi) \pmod{\mathfrak{p}_L^2}$$
the last equality follows from the fact that $\tau$ acts on residual field trivially.
Induction shows $$\tau^q(\sigma(\pi))\equiv a^q\sigma(\pi) \pmod{\mathfrak{p}_L^2}$$

Comparing with $(1)$ shows that $\sigma\tau$ and $\tau^q\sigma$ have same image under $\theta$. Injectivity of $\theta$ proves your claim.