# The Weil group and maximal tame extension

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions, langlands-program

Let $k$ be a $p$-adic field with residue field $\kappa$ of cardinality $q$ and characteristic $p$.

The Weil group $W(k)$ is the subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ of automorphisms that reduce to an integral power of Frobenius $x\mapsto x^q$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\kappa}/\kappa)$. We have the exact sequence $1\to I\to W(k)\to \mathbf{Z}\to 1$, where $I$ is inertia and $\mathbf{Z}$ is the subgroup generated by the image of a Frobenius element $F$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$.

1. Why is this short exact sequence split, i.e. why is $W(k)=I\rtimes \langle F\rangle$, and what is the action of $F$ on $I$? Is it raising to the power $q$? I [read](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632345/frobenius-conjugacy-over-inertia-group-modulo-wild-inertia?noredirect=1&lq=1) that the conjugation action is given by raising to the power $q$ *modulo the wild inertia group $I_+$*.
2. The maximal tame extension $k_t$ is generated by adjoining to the maximal unramified extension $k_u$ all $\sqrt[e]{\pi}$ with $(p,e)=1$ and $\pi$ a uniformiser of $k$. With this description, it is easy to see that $\operatorname{Gal}(k_t/k_u)=\prod_{p\neq l}\mathbf{Z}_\ell$. Somewhere else, I read that $k_t=k_u(\sqrt[q^n-1]{\pi}:n\geq 1)$. With this description, it is easy to see that $\operatorname{Gal}(k_t/k_u)=\varprojlim_n \mathbf{F}_{q^n}^\times$. Why are these two equivalent? Not every $e$ coprime with $p$ is of the form $q^n-1$, right?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: 1. Not sure, but it’s pretty easy to construct group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$? The link you’re quoting is different (it “just” describes the conjugation action of the Frobenius on the tame inertia group)…

Comment: For 2: not every $e$ coprime to $p$ is of the form $q^n-1$, but such an $e$ will divide $q^n-1$ if $n$ is “large enough in the sense of divisibility”.

Comment: There is a canonical choice of $F$ on $T=k(\zeta_{p^\infty-1},p^{1/(p^\infty-1)})$ the maximal tamely ramified subextension of $\overline{k}/k$, but there is no canonical choice on the whole of $\overline{k}$. The canonical choice of $F$ on $T$ is the one leaving $k(p^{1/(p^\infty-1)})$ fixed. The elements of $Gal(T/k)$ are explicit and so is $\rtimes$. It is much more complicated and non-explicit for $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a general fact: if there is a short exact sequence of groups
   $$1\to N\to G\xrightarrow p\mathbb Z\to 1,$$
   then the sequence is split, i.e., $G\cong N\rtimes\mathbb Z$. Indeed, since $p$ is surjective, there exists a $g\in G$ such that $p(g)=1$. Now, $\mathbb Z\to G:1\mapsto g$ gives a splitting.
2. I will expand on what has already been pointed out in the comments: you hope to check
   $$k_u(\sqrt[e]\pi:p\nmid e)=k_u(\sqrt[q^n-1]\pi:n\ge1).$$
   Here, the inclusion $\supseteq$ is clear, since $p\nmid q^n-1$. Conversely, for any $p\nmid e$, we hope to check $\sqrt[e]\pi\in k_u(\sqrt[q^n-1]\pi:n\ge1)$. But there exists a $n\ge1$ (for example $n=\varphi(e)$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function, by Euler's theorem) such that $e|q^n-1$. In other words, there exists an integer $k$ such that $q^n-1=ek$. Now $\sqrt[e]\pi=\sqrt[q^n-1]\pi^k\in k_u(\sqrt[q^n-1]\pi:n\ge1)$.